# Как быть с новым стандартом C++11?

Tags: c++

Сейчас пользуюсь 98/03 и стараюсь не обращать внимание на 11, но мне особо и не приходилось, так как ещё не сталкивался с чем-то, что навязывало бы его. А как у вас обстоят дела? Вы уже наверняка видели как многие используют новый стандарт. Что вы думаете по этому поводу? Есть ли смысл в этом, ведь в бусте и так почти все было. С каким багажом знаний с предыдущего стандарта можно переходить на новый? Так же поговаривают о следующем стандарте в 2014 году. Хоть разорвись).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перейти рано или поздно придется. Проблема в том, что еще не все используемые копмиляторы в достаточной мере поддерживают новый стандарт, а в поддерживающих можно найти баги. Я, например, нашел в gcc4.7 баг в std::regexp, причем то же в boost::regexp работало нормально. Но рано или поздно все устанаканится и станет обычным делом, как уже было с с++2003. Так что учить надо, а вот использовать в реальных проектах, особенно для кого-то, где требуется надежность, я бы пока не стал. А для себя, в виде эксперимента - пожалуйста.

Comment: А что за баг? Расскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если что-то в духе regexp не работает, то это не так страшно. Можно продолжить пользоваться boost`ом в ожидании пока не выйдет 4.9, где этот баг пофикшен, и не отказываться от всего остального.

Comment: @Andrey Buran А почему вы полагаете, что, если есть баг в `std::regexp,` то его нет, например, в `std::thread`?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
Постараюсь как можно короче:
1) Потому что есть http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla (для gcc, ищите багтрекер своей dev platform). Если есть подозрение на проблему, там легко найти ответ - в платформе косяк или в вашем коде.

Comment: 2) Случай с regexp специфический. Его не запилили до конца просто в 4.7, о чём красноречиво свидетельствует табличка http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 То что там отмечено как рабочее (почти все фичи нового стандарта то есть) - РАБОТАЕТ. Я, к слову, всегда относился скептически и к использованию бустовой версии - она ОООЧЕНЬ МЕЕЕЕЕЕДЛЕННАЯ.
3) std::regexp это грбуо говоря не часть языка, это часть библиотеки! Опять же в локальном случае с gcc 4.7 есть же Clang и (о ужас!) MSVS - где он уже реализован.

Comment: 4) В любом случае, даже если есть какие-то проблемы по мелочи (которых нет), старого кода это не касается; самые нужные и облегчающие труд разработчика фичи - работают - так почему нет?

Answer (score 5):

Обязательно надо переходить! Очень много вещей, которые серъёзно облегчают жизнь (auto, decltype, foreach, лямбды и прочее). Ну и вообще, нет смысла оставаться в прошлом ;)

На всякий случай: [C++11 - the new ISO C++ standard](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) (там есть русская версия)

Comment: Угу. После второго

    for (std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>::const_reverse_iterator it = ...

немедленно хочется перейти на `auto` и `foreach`.

Comment: @VladD Да вообще =( Эта строчка кода причиняет мне боль...

Comment: @VladD ну есть более радикальные средства -- послать подальше C++ ...

Comment: ... и пойти работать водителем).